# Javascript scope, how do I preserve the module

Tags: javascript

I have a function which calls itself recursively on a setTimeout. Problem is it loses its scope along the way.

So this is what I have...

```
var module = function () {
    function init() {
        if (notYetReadySoTryAgain) {
            setTimeout(this.init,100);
            return
        }
    }
}
```

The second time through I get an error that init cannot be found (on Window object).

What is the canonical way to deal with maintaining a reference to a module across a setTimeout?

Comment: you do a closure. google search 'javascript closure'

Comment: Where is `notYetReadySoTryAgain` defined ?

Comment: Just omit the [`this` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this), which has nothing to do with scope. You can directly reference the `init` function via `setTimeout(init, 100)` - it's not a property of anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enclose the scope using self-execution; remove `this` as well.

```
var module = function () {
       (function init() {
         if (notYetReadySoTryAgain) {
            setTimeout(init,100);
            return
         }
       })(notYetReadySoTryAgain);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `this.` and it will work.

```
 var module = function () {
   function init() {
     if (notYetReadySoTryAgain) {
        setTimeout(init,100);
        return
     }
   }
}
```

Using `setInterval` can also be option for you.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
   var module = (function () {
            (function init() {
                if (notYetReadySoTryAgain) {
                   setTimeout(init,100);
                    return
                }
            })()
        })()
```